# Does anybody know how to correctly install ANTLR to work with .Net?

Tags: antlr

Can ANTLR output C# using StringTemplate or any text I want it to like Yacc/Bison or does it only output to java?  From the examples I've looked at it appears to be a very java centric tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANTLR IDE has option by which you can switch between Java and C# code generation.

Better, consult this article (the Specifying Code Generation section):

http://www.antlr2.org/doc/csharp-runtime.html

Answer (score 2):

I just started a small series of post about how exactly to install and use ANTLR for a .NET environment, as most documentation regarding this issue is a little out-of-date. See [ANTLR for C#, Part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20140703044347/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/bitsnpieces/archive/2008/12/02/antlr-for-c-part-1-installation.aspx).

Comment: A blog article is always a good thing, thanks for the effort. +1

Answer (score 1):

There is now a NuGet package that will do everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest source code as a tar file from [here](http://antlr.org/download/antlr-3.0.1.tar.gz).  The C# runtime (binary) is also available directly, [here](http://antlr.org/download/DOT-NET-runtime.zip).

Which solution are you looking for?